# Vuex clone object for local editing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using Vue with Vuex for central storage management. 
I have a list of object in the store that are frequently updated by a setTimeout function. I want to let the user select and edit it with a two-way data binding form. My problem is that whenever any data in the store gets updated, also the selected object that is being modified by the user gets re-rendered. In this way the user loses the changes.

The solution would be to clone the object from the Vuex store to a local data object and bind it to the form to prevent updates while editing it. I tried every possible way to clone the observable object that Vuex returns without success.
In particular I tried the following methods:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

and

```
Object.assign({}, vueObj)
```

and also other deep cloning methods from external libraries like _ and jQuery.

this is the object that I get from the Vuex store:

[image]

If i stringify it, parse it and assign to a local vue data object it gets updated whenever the Vuex central storage is updated.

Here is my code (component only, not Vuex store):

```
    <template>
  <div class="">

    <div v-if="localSelectedDataSource.id">
      {{localSelectedDataSource.name}}
    </div>
    <div v-if="localSelectedDataSource.id">
      <div><sui-input placeholder="Url" :value="localSelectedDataSource.url"/></div>
      <div>{{localSelectedDataSource.method}}</div>
      <div>{{localSelectedDataSource.pollingInterval}}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="datasource-list">
      <div
      v-bind:class="{ highlightdatasource: dataSource.view.highlighted }"
      v-for="dataSource in dataSources"
      v-on:mouseover="highlightDataSource(dataSource.id)"
      v-on:mouseout="highlightDataSource(-1)"
      v-on:click="editSelectedDataSourceLocal(dataSource.id)"
      >
        {{dataSource.name}} - {{dataSource.url}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    </template>

      <script>
      import {mapGetters} from 'vuex';
      import {mapActions} from 'vuex';

    export default {
      name: 'DataSourceList',
      data(){
            return{
              localSelectedDataSource: {}
            }
        },
      computed: {
            ...mapGetters([
                'dataSources',
                'selectedDataSource'
            ])
        },
      methods: {
          ...mapActions([
              'highlightDataSource',
              'editSelectedDataSource'
          ]),
          editSelectedDataSourceLocal: function(id){
            this.editSelectedDataSource(id)
            var t = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.selectedDataSource))
            if(this.localSelectedDataSource.id != this.selectedDataSource.id){
              this.localSelectedDataSource = t
            }
          }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Thank you

Comment: are you getting any error ? your cloning should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After many hours of debugging, my friend and I found my error:

I used the v-bind shorthand **:**

```
<div><sui-input placeholder="Url" :value="localSelectedDataSource.url"/></div>
```

rather than two-way binding **v-model**

```
<div><sui-input placeholder="Url" v-model="localSelectedDataSource.url"/></div>
```

so every time that the central vuex store was updated, my component data binding re-rendered, including the local copy bound to the form.

Thanks to everyone,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use v-model you should use a computed property. You'd make a computed property that returns the value that is in the store than use that computed property in the v-model.
By the way v-model is syntactic sugar for:

`:value="someData" @input="someData=$event.target.value"`
It probably works with :value because the @input isn't there.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I figure it out and then I applied the v-model rather than the v-bind.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, this link helped me: [How can I clone data from Vuex state to local data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52581488/how-can-i-clone-data-from-vuex-state-to-local-data) Basically use the `beforeMount()` method, then edit as you please :)