# How can I clone data from Vuex state to local data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

How can I clone data from vuex state to local data attribute?

**State**

this.tsStore.shemes

**Data Attribute**

```js
data () {
  return { shemes: [] }
}
```

I've tried do this in updated () `this.shemes = this.tsStore.shemes` but it's seems like it has a binding left.. because when i delete one item in this.shemes on click i've also delete that item in the state and get the error of "Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers".

I need to clone the state and do what ever I need to do with that data and on the same time don't affect my state state.

Answer (score 25):

Try

```js
this.shemes = JSON.parse ( JSON.stringify ( this.tsStore.shemes) )
```

This will clone all value and objects from the array in the store.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Where should I put this, computed or created?

Comment: It seems that `this.shemes` is empty when I refresh the browser

Comment: data() variables can be accessed only after the component mounts.  Try calling this in mounted()

Comment: console.log( JSON.stringify ( this.tsStore.shemes) ) and check the stringifying procedure. It should show you the scheme in the console

Comment: It's empty on refreshing, but I can see the data from the Vue Console

Comment: If I console.log it in updated() it appear again, I get the data but I'cant do the parse in there, right?

Comment: No, I don't think there is an issue from parsing in updated.

Comment: This does not work if you have dates/sets/maps/etc... in your object, in that case see the (underrated) answer from @kissu below...

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a new array. this.tsStore.shemes give you a reference to the bound array.
You can try to use the spread operator or arr.slice() to create a new array with the same content.
notice that this is a shallow copy.

```js
this.shemes = [...this.tsStore.shemes]
```

or

```js
this.shemes = this.tsStore.shemes.slice()
```

Comment: The spread operator works like a charm. The shallow copy ensures that the original state data is untouched.

Comment: Side problem with this...it only works on the direct properties of the object you are cloning. It does not work if the object you are cloning has nested properties and those nested properties also have getters/setters on them from the state.

It is a REALLY good option, just didn't work for my case of objects within an array, where the array was a property on the watched object.

Answer (score 4):

```js
data(){
  return {
    shemes: null,
  }
},
beforeMount() {
  this.shemes = this.stateShemes
},
computed: {
  stateShemes() { return this.tsState.shemes }
  // OR that's how I do
  stateShemes() { return this.$store.getters['shemes'] }
}
```

**UPDATE**

So you get some value from your state by using computed variables. You cannot just assign the value from you store in the data() block. So you should do it beforeMount. That way if you have a watcher for shemes variable, it won't trigger on assigning computed value. If you put it in mounted() hook, the watcher will trigger.

Also, can you explain why do you use this call `this.tsState.shemes` instead of `this.$store.getters.shemes`?

Comment: Simply posting some code isn't terribly helpful. Can you explain your code? That way others can understand and learn from your answer instead of just copying & pasting some code from the web.

Comment: Sorry for that. Updated my answer.

Comment: tsState is an mapState

Comment: @nahoj did you try me answer? if you have any questions be free to ask me.

Comment: I did and it seems to work but I've got this error when I'm trying to delete/remove an item from `this.shemes` based on click event `Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers`

I'm trying to remove the first item in `this.shemes` with the function `shift()`

Comment: const mutations = {
  'REMOVE_THING' (state, name) {
    state.shemes.shift() },

Comment: this must be in your store. and to call mutation, create an action

Comment: removeSheme ({ commit }, name) {
    commit('REMOVE_THING', name)
  },

Comment: in your vue component: this.$store.dispatch('REMOVE_THING', name)

Answer (score 4):

Using [`cloneDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep) is still [the best way to go](https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-clone-javascript-object/#wrong-solutions), here is an example

```html
<script>
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash-es'

...
const properlyClonedObject = cloneDeep(myDeeplyNestedObject)
...
</script>
```

It's bullet proof, battle-tested and is also a tree-shakable function.

If you need this for Nuxt, here is how to [achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70394677/8816585).

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use 'cloneDeep' instead of creating a deep copy using JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...)) ?

Comment: @mo3n this is explained in my `the best way to go` link!